# how to get a linq query result to int

Tags: c#, linq

below query return a single value eg 50. I want it be assign to int so I can do some calculation with that value. how can I do this

```
var LTLimit = from a in dbavailability.tACLicenseTypes
                  where a.License_Type == "Long Term"
                  select a.Limit;



    string AST = "";
```

Comment: `50` is an `int`. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: You could use Convert, Int.Parse or Int.TryParse. I suggest you try all three to see which one fits your situation best.

Comment: sorry what I mean is the result of the above query I want to multiply by 2 and then covert in to a string value

Comment: It would really help if you showed us the type of `dbavailability.tACLicenseTypes`.  In particular, the type of `tACLicenseTypes.Limit`  That way, we'd know what the type of `LTLimit` is.  Also, instead of saying :"sorry, what I mean is" in a comment, edit your question to make what you mean more clear and add a comment saying "thanks, I've updated and clarified my question"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is one way to retrieve the first integer returned in your query:

```
var LTLimit = (from a in dbavailability.tACLicenseTypes
              where a.License_Type == "Long Term"
              select a.Limit).ToList();

int limit = LTLimit[0];
```

Comment: What will that do if there are no integers in the results?

Comment: There would of course be  an error, but you could add an IF statement to check there are more than 0 items in the List<int>

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely clear on what you're asking, but presumably the type of data returned by your Linq query is *not* `int`, and you want to convert it to int? If so, simply convert it to an int:

```
var LTLimit = (from a in dbavailability.tACLicenseTypes
                  where a.License_Type == "Long Term"
                  select a.Limit).ToList();

int LTLimitInt = 0
if (!int.TryParse(LTLimit.First(), out LTLimitInt))
{
    Console.WritLine("LTLimit is not a number!")
}
```

---

Since you've updated your question, here's a solution to convert the returned number to an  int, multiply it by 2, then convert the result to a string:

```
var LTLimit = (from a in dbavailability.tACLicenseTypes
                  where a.License_Type == "Long Term"
                  select a.Limit).ToList();

int LTLimitInt = 0;
string multipliedResultStr = string.Empty;
if (!int.TryParse(LTLimit.First(), out LTLimitInt))
{
    Console.WritLine("LTLimit is not a number!")
}
else 
{
    multipliedResult = (LTLimitInt * 2).ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result is {0}, multipliedResult ));
}
```

#### Edit;

Corrected code to take first item from list.

Comment: sorry what I mean is the result of the above query I want to multiply by 2 and then covert in to a string value

Comment: @Hobas I've updated my answer take the result from your query, convert it to int, multiply by 2, then convert the result back to string.

Comment: This wil not compile since LTLimit does not produce a single result. It also needs to be executed first.

Answer (score 0):

What is the return type of the query?
If the returned type is of another primative data type like a string, then you can try to convert it to an integer using :

```
var i = Convert.ToInt32(LTLimit);
```

Or using :

```
int.TryParse(LTLimit, out var i);
```

However, it would be better if the data was stored in the correct type in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sum() after where() for value of object property

like this `bonus.Where(b => b.Id == x.key && b.RequiredScore.HasValue).Sum(b => b.RequiredScore.Value);`